# Call View from storyboard with UITabbarController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to implement the 3D quick action for my iOS app.
I've managed to add the quick actions and want to open a viewcontroller in my storyboard.

My root controller is an UITabbarController. Inside this I've an UINavigationController.

I've followed this [tutorial](http://youtu.be/NO9E5KxixOw)

Then I want to open a search view in the appdelegate and I tried to do it like in the tutorial. But I only see a black screen.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.traning.addStuff" {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let searchVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Search") as! SearchView
        let root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController

        root?.presentViewController(searchVC, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
            completionHandler(true)
        })


    }
}
```

My viewcontroller is the third viewcontroller in my UINavigationController

[UITab] -> [UINav] -> [UINav] -> [UINav]

I've tried to initialize the root view as UITabbarController but how I can access or call my view as UINavigationController?

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I've added an image to illustrate my Storyboard (it's just an example)
I have a UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> FirstView -> SecondView

[image]

With the 3D Quick Actions I want call the SecondView.

Comment: A sugestion is try root?.definesPresentationContext = true before you present. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @LucianoAlmeida Hey thank you but it still doesn't work. I'm receiving this log output. Warning: Attempt to present <SearchView: 0x137d741d0> on <UITabBarController: 0x137d93800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Since you have this log, you can try this way:  let root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController. visibleViewController instead. Hope that works :)

Comment: @LucianoAlmeida thank you for your help. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I really don't know what I'ma doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who have the same problem I've found a solution here:
http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2015/10/25/3d-touch-with-tabbarcontroller-and-navigationcontroller

So here is the code I used to call the secondView:

```
if let tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabController.selectedIndex = 1

                let navController = tabController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController
                navController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

                let firstView = navController?.viewControllers[0]
                firstView?.performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: nil)                
            }
```

the tabController.selectedIndex is depending on the view item in your UITabBarController where you want to perform the segue. I my case it was the second item of the UITabBarController.

I hope this helps.